# facing problem in running python code in vs code terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

i am unable to run python code in terminal on vs code
its showing -u what it means?
but i can run it in a interactive screen
i save then file then also facing the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O8BU.png)problem please help

Comment: The file looks like it's not saved

Answer (score 0):

Your Vs Code Window is showing **'No Interpreter'** 
Try reinstalling python and also I guess vs Code is not Up-to-Date.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The dot on the tab means that the current file is not saved, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the file and then run the code.

You can add the following configuration in the **settings.json** to realize the function of saving files in real time.

```json
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
```

##### What does `-u` stand for?

`-u` is an argument to the python command

> -u     : force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered;
> this option has no effect on stdin; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x

There are more parameters you can get by typing `python -h` on the command line

[image]